# Google sheets conditional formatting - All cells must be true

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a hierarchical checklist that will automatically turn green as smaller tasks and their sub-tasks are checked off. [Example Hierarchical Checklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HQRQ.png)

- B1 Contains the Large Task
- B2 is blank for easier viewing
- B3 Contains the Small Task-1
- B4 Contains Small Task-1's 1st Sub Task, C4 contains a checkbox
- B5 Contains Small Task-1's 2nd Sub Task, C5 contains a checkbox
- B6 is blank for easier viewing
- B7 Contains the Small Task-2
- B8 Contains Small Task-2's 1st Sub Task, C8 contains a checkbox
- B9 Contains Small Task-2's 2nd Sub Task, C9 contains a checkbox
- B10 is blank for easier viewing
- B11 Contains the Small Task-3
- B12 Contains Small Task-3's 1st Sub Task, C12 contains a checkbox
- B13 Contains Small Task-3's 2nd Sub Task, C12 contains a checkbox

The Sub-Tasks are pretty simple. If the cell next to it is checked, turn both cells green.

The Smaller Tasks are also pretty simple. For my actual checklist, at most for each Smaller Task, I have 3 sub-tasks. I just used an and condition and specified the specific value to check. `=AND($C4 <> FALSE, $C5 <> FALSE)`

My problem is the larger task. I want to check to see if there are any remaining sub tasks yet to be completed. If not, then turn the entire Larger Task Green. The closest I could get to this is using `=ARRAYFORMULA($C$4:$C$13 <> FALSE)`. This only checks the value of C4, not the entire contents of the range. I also added this same formula to E4 to get an idea of how Google Sheets is processing this formula.

I have tested without any white space in the C* cells, and that didn't change anything.

This cleaning checklist is a small example of my true checklist. I would prefer to not have to create an AND condition with 30 different values to check, but if that's the only way then I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if the number of sub tasks `COUNTA(B3:B)` equals to the number of sub tasks that are completed `COUNTIF(C3:C,TRUE)`.

```
=COUNTA(B3:B)=COUNTIF(C3:C,TRUE)
```